# Pandas group by a column but preserve the order

Tags: python, pandas

I want to group my dataframe by 2 columns (`orig` and `dest`) to calculate the total `qty` per `orig-dest` pair but don't want the group by to change the order. I need the results of the `groupby` to be ordered based on the ascending `Drivetime`.

In the e.g. below the drivetime from `A to B1` is 1 and from `A to A1` is 4 and so I need the `groupby` to return `A to B1` as the first result and `A to A1` as the second result. Right now, the results default to being alphabetically ordered. The reason I need it this way is because in the next step I want to calculate the cumulative percentage of `qty` per `orig`, and therefore the order matters. Can someone please help.

```
import pandas as pd

#Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Orig': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'] ,
                   'Dest': ['A1', 'A1', 'B1', 'B2','C1'] ,
                   'Qty': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
                      'Drivetime':[4,4,1,3,5]})

#Rank the data for each orig in increasing order of drivetimes
df.sort_values(by =['Orig', 'Drivetime'], inplace=True)
df

#Calculate the total quantity per orig
total_qty_per_orig = df.groupby(['Orig', 'Dest']).agg({'Qty': 'sum'})
total_qty_per_orig
```

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['Orig', 'Dest'], sort=False).agg({'Qty': 'sum'})`

Comment: @jezrael that's awesome! Didn't know it was that simple! thanks a lot :)